# Problem with how circuit work in china transformerless voltage sensor pilot lamp

Tags: voltage, sensor, power-electronics, transformerless

I want to actually understand the circuit completely but for the specific, i want to really understand how this circuit can actually output ac voltage in OUTPUT_SENSOR point and the waveform is completely sinus without any signal cuts within the negative period.
At anode of D3 the waveform i see with oscilloscope is half-wave with positive periode is cutted.
The led is only my sample load, actually in real it is connected to ic for outputting voltage value with 7-segment.

[image: From transformerless voltage sensor pilot lamp made in china]

[image: This picture of ac signal at D3 anode]

[image: This picture of ac signal at output or at D3 cathode]

Comment: This circuit is voltage doubler. During negative period is charged C1 to Vin and during positive period is charge from C1 together with Vin transfered to C2. At the output sensor node should be only positive period of Vin AC signal decreased by deviders R2,R4 (R1 can be neglected). Negative period is clamped due to D3 reverse biasing.

Comment: The voltage at the output (at C2) depends mainly on size of C1 becouse it determines how much charge is tranfered to C2. So this way you can regulate the output voltage and make a simple "transformer". Of course this voltage is a lot of load dependent, so after higher loading the output voltage rapidly decreses what makes this circuit suitable for constant loads only .

Comment: @Dimas please ask a specific question